# mysql subquery select with field from query

Tags: mysql, subquery

i  have a little problem with a subquery in sql.
her the query

```
SELECT st.title, count(q.id) as question_count, max(a.id) as maxid,
            sum(case when a.answer is not null then 1 else 0 end) as answer_count, g.user_id as game_user_id,
            a.game_id as a_game_id, a.modified as finished, (select modified as finished from answers a where a.id = g.maxid limit 1) as subquery
        FROM games g
        left join answers a on(a.game_id = g.id)
        left join questions q on(a.question_id = q.id)
        left join sessions s on(s.id = q.session_id)
        left join sessiontypes st on(st.id = s.sessiontype_id)
        WHERE g.user_id = 21
        group by g.id
        having(question_count = answer_count)
        order by finished DESC;
```

i want that the subquery returns the modified value from answers where the id is the highest grouped by game.

so i tried to `select max(id) as maxid...` and the use max id in the subquery. `where a.id = maxid`. nice try, but dont work.
mysql error is this one: `Reference 'maxid' not supported (reference to group function)`

can anybody give a hint how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join on a subquery which returns the `MAX(answers.id)` grouped by the `answers.game_id`.

Then use that `maxid` to join on the `answers` table to get the row of the corresponding `answers.id`.

Not sure, how your result is supposed to look, in your select I removed `a.modified AS finished,` and replaced it with the `modified` column of the row with maxid.

```
SELECT
    st.title,
    count(q.id) AS question_count,
    sum(
        CASE
        WHEN a.answer IS NOT NULL THEN
            1
        ELSE
            0
        END
    ) AS answer_count,
    g.user_id AS game_user_id,
    a.maxid,
    a.game_id AS a_game_id,
    modifiedAnswer.modified AS finished,
FROM
    games g

LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(answers.id) AS maxid, game_id FROM answers GROUP BY answers.game_id) AS a ON (a.game_id = g.id)
LEFT JOIN answers AS modifiedAnswer ON modifiedAnswer.id = a.maxid 

LEFT JOIN questions q ON (a.question_id = q.id)
LEFT JOIN sessions s ON (s.id = q.session_id)
LEFT JOIN sessiontypes st ON (st.id = s.sessiontype_id)
WHERE
    g.user_id = 21
GROUP BY
    g.id
HAVING
    (
        question_count = answer_count
    )
ORDER BY
    finished DESC;
```

Comment: Hm, i think i know what you mean. but your query does not work. ;)

Comment: Can you give some data? + expected result, + errormessage for this query. Though I think I messed up the alias in the subquery, put it after game_id instead after id. Fixed in the query

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you for that. no i get what i want :)
this sql is very confusing :P

Comment: It takes a while (and some practice) to get into the right thinking :) Can you accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: yes accepted. some tutorials would be good. but the most is only text text text... :P

Comment: Try this one: http://wwwlgis.informatik.uni-kl.de/extra/game/ it's a game in which you use sql to do stuff